# Why does application name displayed as ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME in application manager

Tags: android

Name of my application is displayed correctly in the launcher (after it is installed), but it is displayed as ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME in the application manager. Install and uninstall dialogs also shows its name as ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME. I have also tried to map ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME in strings.xml but it did not worked.

```
<string name="app_name">Kargo Takibi</string>
<string name="activity_entry_name">Kargo Takibi</string>
```

Comment: Did you search for ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME in your Manifest.xml? You may have a class with that name in there.

Comment: Try to search "ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME" string in all projects which you have. I believe it's not declared value of Android sdk.

Comment: It was not in my project but one of the projects listed in dependencies of my project. Thanks.